# Regex to search in reverse

Tags: php, regex

**Haystack**: `14201-33-0.html`

**Needle**: `0`

Regex: `((?:-[^-]*))$`

Matches:
`-0.html`

So I need to capture the digits from the last `-` until the `.`, excluding those chars themselves. I'm not good with regex so can't quite figure how to match `0` exactly. It can be 1 or 2 digits in place of `0`.

Comment: Check https://regex101.com/r/C5lHwc/1 and https://regex101.com/r/C5lHwc/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
'~-(\d+)\.\D*$~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ikzhct/2)

**Details**:

- `-` - a hyphen
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `\D*` - zero or more chars other than digits (this may be changed to `[a-zA-Z]+` or specific list of extensions, e.g. `(?:html?|php)`)
- `$` - end of string.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/wrgxXm):

```
$re = '~-(\d+)\.\D*$~';
$str = '14201-33-0.html';
if (preg_match($re, $str, $match)) {
 echo $match[1];
}
```